# Extracting first n columns of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
  array([[-0.57098887, -0.4274751 , -0.38459931, -0.58593526],
         [-0.22279713, -0.51723555,  0.82462029,  0.05319973],
         [ 0.67492385, -0.69294472, -0.2531966 ,  0.01403201],
         [ 0.41086611,  0.26374238,  0.32859738, -0.80848795]])
```

Now I want to extract the following:

```
   [-0.57098887, -0.4274751]
   [-0.22279713, -0.51723555]
   [ 0.67492385, -0.69294472]
   [ 0.41086611,  0.26374238]
```

So basically just first 2 columns..

Comment: Numpy documentation: [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing). Always check the documentation first.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Thanks.. so slicing is the term.. it gets pretty hard if you know the concept but not the term.. :) many thanks :)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If `a` is your array:

```
In [11]: a[:,:2]
Out[11]: 
array([[-0.57098887, -0.4274751 ],
       [-0.22279713, -0.51723555],
       [ 0.67492385, -0.69294472],
       [ 0.41086611,  0.26374238]])
```

Answer (score 32):

I know this is quite an old question -

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
```

Let's say, you want to extract the first 2 rows and first 3 columns

```
A_NEW = A[0:2, 0:3]
A_NEW = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6]]
```

Understanding the syntax

```
A_NEW = A[start_index_row : stop_index_row, 
          start_index_column : stop_index_column)]
```

If one wants row 2 and column 2 and 3

```
A_NEW = A[1:2, 1:3]
```

Reference the numpy indexing and slicing article - [Indexing & Slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)