# Selecting columns from multi-dimensional numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I created a multi-dimensional numpy array using this code:

```
pt=[[0 for j in range(intervals+1)] for i in range(users+1)]
```

A `print (np.shape(pt)) gives me

```
(1001,169)
```

I then proceeded to populate the array (code not shown) before trying to select everything but the first column to feed into matplotlib.

I referred to posts on how to select columns from a multi-dimensional array:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455076/how-to-access-the-ith-column-of-a-numpy-multidimensional-array)
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386675/extracting-specific-columns-in-numpy-array)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625096/extracting-first-n-columns-of-a-numpy-matrix)

all of whom say I should do:

```
pt[:,1:]
```

to select everything but the first column. However this gives me the error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: This seems like a list, not a numpy array...

Comment: Why not simply `numpy.zeros((users + 1, intervals + 1), dtype=int)`?

Comment: @Markus - You are absolutely correct. I just realized this. People like this (http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/3942-arrays-in-python.html?start=1) are to blame. For goodness sake don't say "For a programmer moving to Python the problem is that there are no explicit provisions for multidimensional arrays. As a list can contain any type of data there is no need to create a special two-dimensional data structure. All you have to do is store lists within lists".

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else that reaches this post from having made the same mistake (see comments above), if you want to continue using lists then do pt[:][0:1]  but really I recommend switching to numpy and ignoring all the results you get when you search for 'declaring python array'